# What does DefaultListModel.contains() does?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, collections, defaultlistmodel

I am watching the following expressions in Eclipse debugger

```
downsPanel.relsListModel.elementAt(4)==oldValue
```

and

```
downsPanel.relsListModel.contains(oldValue)
```

First of them evaluates to `true`, and second -- to `false`.

This means that `contains()` does not does what I expect. What does it does then?

Comment: What's the class of oldValue ? Does it have a very strange equals method ?

Comment: You were right, I forgot to fix `equals()` after refactor so that it was returning `false` for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing both tests were done at the same point, this can mean only one thing : `oldValue.equals(oldValue)` returns `false`.

So the problem is in the `equals` method which must be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultListModel.contains(Object)` delegates to the backing `Vector`'s `contains`.

```
public boolean contains(Object elem) {
    return delegate.contains(elem);
}
```

Perhaps this is an `equals` related issue (don't forget to fix `hashCode` as well).